# Find the orders of zeros for a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the orders of zeros for the following functions at z = 0:

1.$$ z^2 (e^{z^2} - 1) $$

2.

$$ 6 \sin(z^3) + z^3 (z^6 - 6)  $$

The question means that I should set both functions to zero and find the solution. If one of the solutions is zero, then find how many times it is repeated, correct?

Comment: No---the problem tells you that both of the functions have a zero at $z = 0$, and for each function you're asked to find the order of the zero at that point. NB it's easier to treat these particular cases (as is often the case) using power series than it is using derivatives---the orders turn out to be large (especially in the second case).

Comment: So the approach would be to find the Taylor expansion for both and then set them equal to zero?

Comment: No, it's simpler than that; I've worked out the order of the zero for the first function in detail in an answer. The procedure for the second function is the same (but the details are a little more involved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No---the problem tells you that both of the functions have a zero at $z = 0$, and for each function you're asked to find the order of the zero at that point. NB it's easier to treat these particular cases (as is often the case) using power series than it is using derivatives---the orders turn out to be large (especially in the second case).

For example, in the first case, substituting $w = z^2$ in the Taylor series $e^w \sim \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} w^k$ gives
\begin{align}
z^2\left(e^{z^2} - 1\right)
&\sim z^2 \left(-1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} z^{2k}\right) \\
&= z^2 \left(-1 + 1 + z^2 + \tfrac{1}{2} z^4 + \cdots \right) \\
&= z^4 + \tfrac{1}{2} z^6 + \cdots .
\end{align}
Since the lowest-order term in the series is $z^4$, we can factor this function as
$$z^4 \left(1 + \tfrac{1}{2} z^2 + \cdots\right) .$$
So, $z \mapsto z^2\left(e^{z^2} - 1\right)$ can be written as the product of $z^4$ and some function whose value at $z = 0$ is nonzero, i.e., that function has a zero of order (precisely) $\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{4}}$ at $z = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the second example and found that the order is 3. Is there a way I can check my answer? Or is this the correct answer?

Comment: You're welcome. I get order $15$ for the second function (this alone is a great advertisement for working with power series instead of computing derivatives repeatedly).

Comment: I got 15 this time lol. I must be spending too much time on complex analysis to the point where I started to get problems mixed up. Thanks for all the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome.